# Prevent an iOS app from being updated

Tags: ios

I am doing some research to find out if an app developer can set up an app in a way that it can't be updated, at least in some circumstance.

Or in another way: what can be done by a developer in order to create on purpose issue during the update of its own app?

Comment: What do you mean "can't be updated"? Do you mean get the App Store to no longer allow new updates to the app?

Comment: don't release updates. case solved.

Comment: 1. No, there's not a way. 2. What is your goal by doing this?

Comment: I mean that it shouldn't be updated also by a developer when testing on his own device. I want to be able to create a fixed single version of an app. If I want a new version of that app I have to create a new Xcode project with a new and different bundle identifier. I hope now it is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you actually want to do is create another Target in your project. This way, you can have multiple copies of your app on the same device. For example, you could have a dev target that is constantly moving and a release target that you don't want to override.

You can do this by selecting your project in the project navigator, right clicking on your app's target, and then selecting `Duplicate`. It will create a new target called `YourAppName-copy`. You can then select your target next to where you select the device/simulator to run on & select the new target. Run the new target & it will install the new target and leave your other one alone.

Answer (score -1):

For an enterprise app, you could support your own app updating (and create a web service to check to see if the app needs to be updated -- or if the user's credentials are still valid, etc.).

For a public App Store app, this is not currently possible.